# Android: Dynamically adding views to the Container view

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Hi am creating the row items dynamically, when ever i click on the Button am inflating the row of edittexts and adding it to my container. I have spinner in the row, For the particular spinner i am setting a array adapter.

The problem is when trying to add another row with spinner  i need the same set of array adapater to be set second row spinner also but this is creating a problem, which disturbs the first spinner as both are from same xml file.

How to give multiple ids to the spinner and treat them as different spinners.

```
 addviewbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                        (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_row, null);
                container.addView(addView);
                for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = container.getChildAt(i);


                    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.product);

                    String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "three"};
                   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }
        });
```

**quote_row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView04h" android:text="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="10dp" android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="10dp" android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/product"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="10dp" android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/unitprice"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="10dp" android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/exactprice"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="10dp" android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>



    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: place quote_row xml.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal    added xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = container.getChildAt(i);
TableLayout table=(TableLayout)view.findViewbyId(R.id.table);
TableRow row=(TableRow)table.getChildAt(0);
spinner = (Spinner) row.getChildAt(2);
```